# have a date input. If the user is on mobile and has 24hr time that is how it is inputed. need standard time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

basically since the input is type date. then the mobile phone pulls up a scrollwheel keyboard and if they have 24 hour time that is how it is inputted.

I would like to either make it so the user with a phone that has 24 hour time still has to input it the regular way on the form.

or if it is easier. I would like to in the case of them entering 24 hour time. convert it to standard time when they click done on their keyboard, or if thats not possible atleast when the form submits.

here is a function that converts 24 hour time to standard

```
function formatDate(date) {
  var d = new Date(date);
  var hh = d.getHours();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
  var dd = "AM";
  var h = hh;
  if (h >= 12) {
    h = hh - 12;
    dd = "PM";
  }
  if (h == 0) {
    h = 12;
  }
  m = m < 10 ? "0" + m : m;

  s = s < 10 ? "0" + s : s;

  /* if you want 2 digit hours:
  h = h<10?"0"+h:h; */

  var pattern = new RegExp("0?" + hh + ":" + m + ":" + s);

  var replacement = h + ":" + m;
  /* if you want to add seconds
  replacement += ":"+s;  */
  replacement += " " + dd;

  return date.replace(pattern, replacement);
}
```

Comment: *"convert it to standard time when they click done on their keyboard"* - In my opinion that would be the best place to do it, so that the user enters the time in their own preferred format, but if they get confused and forget they're on 24-hour time they'd immediately see that they got "am" when they meant "pm". (Though presumably they've selected 24-hour format for a reason.) In my opinion forcing them to have to type "am" or "pm" is the worst option.

Comment: Yeah that seems like the best bet. Unfortunatley my javascript knowledge is quite limited so I have no I idea how to make this actually happen with this function. And the function does not take into account that they may be using a standard keyboard